# I got unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args' after installing Django extensions

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django website. I was recently using the management command runserver_plus provided by Django Extensions to run the development server. When I attempt to run the website through terminal I receive the error message:

```
C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\DJANGO\website> python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file 
cert.crt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
279, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 
48, in load_command_class
module = import_module("%s.management.commands.%s" % (app_name, name))
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\django_extensions\management\commands\runserver_plus.py", line 40, in <module>
from django_extensions.management.utils import RedirectHandler, has_ipdb, setup_logger, 
signalcommand
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\utils.py", 
line 6, in <module>
from django_extensions.management.signals import post_command, pre_command
File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\signals.py", 
line 13, in <module>
pre_command = Signal(providing_args=["args", "kwargs"])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/) for django-extensions, the highest Django version it supports is `3.2`. The `providing_args` argument for `django.dispatch.Signal` was [removed in Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0), and based on your error you seem to be using that version or later.